# How to Justify Text in Paracol

Tags: paracol, parallel-texts

I'm using the `paracol` package for a parallel translation. I have noticed sometimes that the text overruns its column and into the next column. Also, the Latin in this example does not justify. Is there anyway to solve both of these problems and get the text to properly justify? An example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lettrine[lines=2]{I}{} \textsc{confess} to almighty God, to blessed Mary ever virgin, to blessed Michael the archangel, to blessed John the Baptist, to the holy apostles Peter and Paul, to all the saints, and to you, brethren, that I have sinned exceedingly in thought, word, and deed: (\emph{The priest strikes his breast three times, saying:}) through my fault, through my fault, through my most grievous fault. Therefore I beseech the blessed Mary ever virgin, blessed Michael the archangel, blessed John the Baptist, the holy apostles Peter and Paul, all the saints, and you, brethren, to pray to the Lord our God for me.
\switchcolumn
\lettrine[lines=2]{C}o\textsc{nfiteor} Deo omnipotenti, beatæ Mariæ semper virgini, beato Micheali archangelo, beato Joanni Baptistæ, sanctis Apostolis Petro et Paulo, omnibus Sanctis et vocis fratres, quia peccavi nimis cogitatione, verbo, et opere: mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa. Ideo precor beatam Mariam semper virgenem, beatum Michaelem archangelum, beatum Joanem Baptistam, sanctos Apostolos Petrum et Paulum, omnes Sanctos et vos fratres, orare pro me ad Dominum Deum nostrum.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:
[image]

Comment: This is probably due to the hyphenation algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Actually, the English column is not completely justified either.  Both columns could use a little more space-stretchability, and there are words that will need help with hyphenation.  There do exist hyphenation patterns for Latin.  I will look to see if there's some other question that addresses this.  I'm not familiar enough with `paracol` to know the defaults for such things.

Comment: Note that `[lines=2]` for `\lettrine` is unnecessary, as that is the default.  If you do want to change it, you could set in your preamble, `\setcounter{DefaultLines}{2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if `paracol` change the penalties of line breaks is some way, but this issue has little to do with `paracol` but with the fact of having narrow columns, so the text will need some hyphens, but you  do not inform to LaTeX of what languages you are using, so (1) LaTeX cannot apply the right hyphenation rules, so a first solution is use `babel`. Even then, hyphenation of some words could be problematic, and then you can add some soft hyphens manually (`\-`), or use the package `microtype` help also to minimize this kind of problems, and/or play with `\emergencystretch` to better distribute the spaces within the paragraph.  One way to add a generous `\emergencystretch` of 3em (and also increase  the `\tolerance` to badness) is just add  `\sloppy` (in the preamble, for instance). Note that in this case `\sloppy`  is enough to produce a decent result (not showed in the example) but the use of babel and microtype are recomendable anyway.

Beside this, off-topic,  `\textsc` is not necessary at all, as the second argument of \lettrine is by default typed with small captions:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english, latin]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\selectlanguage{english}
\lettrine[lines=2]{I}{ confess} to almighty God, to blessed Mary ever virgin, to blessed Michael the archangel, to blessed John the Baptist, to the holy apostles Peter and Paul, to all the saints, and to you, brethren, that I have sinned exceedingly in thought, word, and deed: (\emph{The priest strikes his breast three times, saying:}) through my fault, through my fault, through my most grievous fault. Therefore I beseech the blessed Mary ever virgin, blessed Michael the archangel, blessed John the Baptist, the holy apostles Peter and Paul, all the saints, and you, brethren, to pray to the Lord our God for me.
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}

\switchcolumn
\selectlanguage{latin}
\lettrine[lines=2]{C}{onfiteor} Deo omnipotenti, beatæ Mariæ semper virgini, beato Micheali archangelo, beato Joanni Baptistæ, sanctis Apostolis Petro et Paulo, omnibus Sanctis et vocis fratres, quia peccavi nimis cogitatione, verbo, et opere: mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa. Ideo precor beatam Mariam semper virgenem, beatum Michaelem archangelum, beatum Joanem Baptistam, sanctos Apostolos Petrum et Paulum, omnes Sanctos et vos fratres, orare pro me ad Dominum Deum nostrum.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Fran beat me to an answer, but I’d already written a solution that automates parallel, vertically-aligned columns that switch languages, so I’ll go ahead and post it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype} % Enable font expansion.

\emergencystretch=3em % Allow wide word spacing as an alternative to paragraph breaking.
\columnsep=2em
\pagestyle{empty}

% Command for parallel multilingual columns within a paracol environment:
\newcommand\obverses[2]{%
  \begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{otherlanguage}{english}%
  {#1}%
  \end{otherlanguage}\end{leftcolumn*}%
  \begin{rightcolumn}\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
  {#2}%
  \end{otherlanguage}\end{rightcolumn}%
}

\columnsep=2em

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\obverses
{\lettrine{B}{ut} I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of reprobating pleasure and extolling pain arose. To do so, I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?}
{\lettrine{S}{ed} ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, \textbf{qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing velit,} sed quia non numquam do eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum irure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?}

\obverses
{On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammeled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.}
{ At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]