# Text does not justify by default in paracol

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, paracol, justification

When I use package `paracol`, my text does not justify by default. I have checked several other questions related to this, such as [How to Justify Text in Paracol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659026/how-to-justify-text-in-paracol).

I have also tried the standard remedies, such as microtype, emergencystretch, and setting a badness of 5,000. These have made my English column come very close to being justified, but not completely. And my Latin text is not affected. Rather, my text is generically centered, which (to my knowledge) I have not told it to do. This is confusing because it's my impression that (La)TeX justifies by default.

Here is a code sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[main=latin, american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnsep=1em
\emergenystretch=3em
\newcommand{\vssm}{\vskip 0.05in}
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
%\title{Lamentabili}
%\author{St. Pius X}
%\date{3 July, 1907}
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\textsc{\center
\huge Lamentabili\\
\vskip 0.10in
\Large St. Pius X\\
1907\\
}
\vskip 0.10in
\hrule
%
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\setcolumnwidth{1\textwidth/20pt, 1\textwidth}
\hbadness20000
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%Preamble 0
%%%%%%%%%%
\center{DECRETUM}
\vskip 0.10in
\textit{Quo sub 65 propositionibus reprobantur ac proscribuntur praecipui errores reformismi seu modernismi.}
\vskip 0.10in
Feria IV, die 3 Iulii 1907.
\vskip 0.10in
\switchcolumn
\center{DECREE}
\vskip 0.10in
\textit{In which 65 propositions are reproved and proscribed as errors of Reformism or Modernism.}
\vskip 0.10in
Wednesday, July 3, 1907.
\vskip 0.10in
\switchcolumn*
%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%Preamble 1
%%%%%%%%%%
\textsc{Lamentabili sane exitu} aetas nostra freni impatiens in rerum summis rationibus indagandis ita nova non raro sequitur ut, divisa humani generis quasi haereditate, in errores incidat gravisimos. Qui errores longe erunt perniciosiores, si de disciplinis agitur sacris, si de Sacra Scriptura interpretanda, si de fidei praecipuis mysteriis. Dolendum autem vehementer inveniri etiam inter catholicos non ita paucos scriptores qui, praetergressi fines a Patribus ac ab ipsa Sancta Ecclesia statutos, altioris intelligentiae specie et historicae considerationis nomine, eum dogmatum progressum quaerunt qui, reipsa, eorum corruptela est.
\vssm
\switchcolumn
With truly lamentable results, our age, casting aside all restraint in its search for the ultimate causes of things, frequently pursues novelties so ardently that it rejects the legacy of the human race. Thus it falls into very serious errors, which are even more serious when they concern sacred authority, the interpretation of Sacred Scripture, and the principal mysteries of Faith. The fact that many Catholic writers also go beyond the limits determined by the Fathers and the Church herself is extremely regrettable. In the name of higher knowledge and historical research (they say), they are looking for that progress of dogmas which is, in reality, nothing but the corruption of dogmas.
\vssm
\switchcolumn*
```

Which produces:

[image: Example of text to-be-justified]

Thank you.

Edit: In the example, the badness is set to 20,000, which I did out of desperation.

Comment: you  are specifying all lines should be centred not justified. `\center` should not be used in a document, it is the internal form of `\begin{center}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\center` should never be used in a document, it is the internal implementation of `\begin{center}`  so if you use

```
\center{DECRETUM}
```

it is like `\begin{center}DECRETUM` except that as there is no group containing the scope, the whole document uses centred, rather than justified, linebreaking.
The braces around DECRETUM do nothing.

replace

```
\center{DECREE}
\vskip 0.10in
```

by

```
\begin{center}
DECREE
\end{center}
```